# XML parser in xcode only returns first entry

Tags: xcode, nsxmlparser

I'm using the following code to parse an xml file. But it only returns the first entry of the xml file. I can't seem to find the cause of the problem. I thought it did return all entries at first but when I ran my app again only three entries showed up. Another try and only the first one shows up. Now I just get the first entry every time.

Update I found out the error was due to HTML entities in my xml. But now that I have decoded these when I parse the file. UTF-8 encoded characters show up in my strings like é shows up like Ã©

THPRSSParser.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSString+HTML.h"

@interface THPRSSFeedParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>

- (NSMutableArray *)getNews;

@end
```

THPRSSParser.m

```
    #import "THPRSSFeedParser.h"

@implementation THPRSSFeedParser {

    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feed;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *guid;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *content;
    NSMutableString *description;
    NSMutableString *url;
    NSMutableString *pubdate;
    NSString *element;

}

- (NSMutableArray *)getNews {
    feed = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *feedurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/rss.php"];
    NSData *feedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:feedurl];

    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:feedData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    result = [result stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];

    feedData = [result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:feedData];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

    return feed;
}


//NSString *correctString = [NSString stringWithCString:[utf8String cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        guid = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        content = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        description = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        url    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        pubdate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:guid forKey:@"guid"];
        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:content forKey:@"content:encoded"];
        [item setObject:description forKey:@"description"];
        [item setObject:url forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:pubdate forKey:@"pubDate"];
        [feed addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"guid"]) {
        [guid appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"content:encoded"]) {
        [content appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [description appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [url appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [pubdate appendString:string];
    }
}

@end
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
  <channel>
    <title>Rembrandt College Veenendaal nieuws</title>
    <link>http://rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws</link>
    <description></description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 01 Oct 2014 12:17:40 +0100</pubDate>
    <item>
      <title>Nieuws van 1 mei</title>
      <link>http://rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/1/Nieuws+van+1+mei</link>
      <description>Korte beschrijving nieuws 1 mei</description>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">1</guid>
      <pubDate>Thu, 01 May 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
      <content:encoded>Lange beschrijving nieuws 1 mei
      Met een extra regel hier!
      En hier!</content:encoded>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Nieuws van 10 juni</title>
      <link>http://rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/2/Nieuws+van+10+juni</link>
      <description>Korte beschrijving
      voor het nieuws
      van 10 juni</description>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">2</guid>
      <pubDate>Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
      <content:encoded>Voor de leerlingen van groep 8 is het laatste jaar op de basisschool een belangrijk jaar. Nog &eacute;&eacute;n jaar op de basisschool, een jaar om te laten zien wat ze in hun mars hebben. Een jaar waarin de keuze voor een vervolgschool moet worden gemaakt. Een spannend en enerverend jaar voor kinderen van 11 &ndash; 12 jaar en ook voor hun ouders.
      Leerlingen uit groep 8 willen zich een beeld vormen van de &ldquo;middelbare school&rdquo;. Daarom organiseren wij een ori&euml;ntatie op het Voortgezet Onderwijs speciaal voor deze leerlingen.
      Het doel van de inloopmiddag is om leerlingen, samen met de klasgenoten en de eigen docent, in het echt kennis te laten maken met het Voortgezet Onderwijs, kennis te laten maken met nieuwe vakken en de sfeer van de &ldquo;middelbare&rdquo; school te proeven. En niet te vergeten, om vragen te stellen.</content:encoded>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Plaatjes voor het nieuws werken nu ook</title>
      <link>http://rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/4/Plaatjes+voor+het+nieuws+werken+nu+ook</link>
      <description>Plaatjes... plaatjes everywhere!</description>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">4</guid>
      <pubDate>Wed, 02 Jul 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
      <content:encoded>Ze zijn te vinden op:
      http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/_db/news/_thumb/4.jpg
      Auto-resize staat op 200x200
      en
      http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/_db/news/4.jpg
      Auto-resize staat op 400x400</content:encoded>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Brugklas kamp</title>
      <link>http://rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/3/Brugklas+kamp</link>
      <description>Korte beschrijving nieuws 1 augustus met bacon ipsum tekst.</description>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">3</guid>
      <pubDate>Fri, 01 Aug 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
      <content:encoded>Natuurlijk is het even schrikken als je vers van de basisschool bij ons op het Rembrandt terecht komt. Je zult wel moeten wennen. Meteen in het begin van het schooljaar gaan de brugklassen een aantal dagen op kamp. Dit doen we vooral, omdat je elkaar dan snel goed leert kennen. Een paar dagen met elkaar op stap dat helpt je snel aan de nieuwe situatie wennen. Na een paar dagen van dans, sport en natuurlijk ook ontspanning is het Rembrandt College helemaal jouw school.&nbsp;De foto's van het brugklaskamp kunt je terug vinden in het fotoboek.</content:encoded>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Rembrandt en talent</title>
      <link>http://rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/5/Rembrandt+en+talent</link>
      <description></description>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">5</guid>
      <pubDate>Wed, 17 Sep 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
      <content:encoded>Het Rembrandt college had een aantal brilliante natuurkundigen op bezoek.</content:encoded>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Nieuws van 29 september</title>
      <link>http://rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/6/Nieuws+van+29+september</link>
      <description></description>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">6</guid>
      <pubDate>Tue, 30 Sep 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
      <content:encoded>In 2007 hadden we de geweldige klassieker Romeo en Julia op onze school. Vele uren oefenen, veel werk en veel plezier leverden een prachtige voorstelling op waar ouders, broers en zussen, neven en nichten en vrienden en vriendinnen hebben genoten van vakwerk op het podium.
      Het plezier en de kwaliteit spatten van het podium. Een echte Rembrandt voorstelling onder de bezielende leiding van Mette Spruit. In het fotoboek krijg je een goede indruk van deze voorstelling. Er is ook een prachtig fotoboek verschenen.
      &nbsp;</content:encoded>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

xml after decoding HTML entities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
<channel>
<title>Rembrandt College Veenendaal nieuws</title>
<link>http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws</link>
<description></description>
<pubDate>Wed, 01 Oct 2014 14:19:30 +0100</pubDate>
<item>
<title>Nieuws van 1 mei</title>
<link>http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/1/Nieuws+van+1+mei</link>
<description>Korte beschrijving nieuws 1 mei</description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">1</guid>
<pubDate>Thu, 01 May 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
<content:encoded>Lange beschrijving nieuws 1 mei
Met een extra regel hier!
En hier!</content:encoded>
</item>
<item>
<title>Nieuws van 10 juni</title>
<link>http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/2/Nieuws+van+10+juni</link>
<description>Korte beschrijving
voor het nieuws
van 10 juni</description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">2</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 10 Jun 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
<content:encoded>Voor de leerlingen van groep 8 is het laatste jaar op de basisschool een belangrijk jaar. Nog één jaar op de basisschool, een jaar om te laten zien wat ze in hun mars hebben. Een jaar waarin de keuze voor een vervolgschool moet worden gemaakt. Een spannend en enerverend jaar voor kinderen van 11 – 12 jaar en ook voor hun ouders.
Leerlingen uit groep 8 willen zich een beeld vormen van de “middelbare school”. Daarom organiseren wij een oriëntatie op het Voortgezet Onderwijs speciaal voor deze leerlingen.
Het doel van de inloopmiddag is om leerlingen, samen met de klasgenoten en de eigen docent, in het echt kennis te laten maken met het Voortgezet Onderwijs, kennis te laten maken met nieuwe vakken en de sfeer van de “middelbare” school te proeven. En niet te vergeten, om vragen te stellen.</content:encoded>
</item>
<item>
<title>Plaatjes voor het nieuws werken nu ook</title>
<link>http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/4/Plaatjes+voor+het+nieuws+werken+nu+ook</link>
<description>Plaatjes... plaatjes everywhere!</description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">4</guid>
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Jul 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
<content:encoded>Ze zijn te vinden op:
http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/_db/news/_thumb/4.jpg
Auto-resize staat op 200x200
en
http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/_db/news/4.jpg
Auto-resize staat op 400x400</content:encoded>
</item>
<item>
<title>Brugklas kamp</title>
<link>http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/3/Brugklas+kamp</link>
<description>Korte beschrijving nieuws 1 augustus met bacon ipsum tekst.</description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">3</guid>
<pubDate>Fri, 01 Aug 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
<content:encoded>Natuurlijk is het even schrikken als je vers van de basisschool bij ons op het Rembrandt terecht komt. Je zult wel moeten wennen. Meteen in het begin van het schooljaar gaan de brugklassen een aantal dagen op kamp. Dit doen we vooral, omdat je elkaar dan snel goed leert kennen. Een paar dagen met elkaar op stap dat helpt je snel aan de nieuwe situatie wennen. Na een paar dagen van dans, sport en natuurlijk ook ontspanning is het Rembrandt College helemaal jouw school. De foto's van het brugklaskamp kunt je terug vinden in het fotoboek.</content:encoded>
</item>
<item>
<title>Rembrandt en talent</title>
<link>http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/5/Rembrandt+en+talent</link>
<description></description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">5</guid>
<pubDate>Wed, 17 Sep 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
<content:encoded>Het Rembrandt college had een aantal brilliante natuurkundigen op bezoek.</content:encoded>
</item>
<item>
<title>Nieuws van 29 september</title>
<link>http://www.rembrandt-college.nl/nieuws/6/Nieuws+van+29+september</link>
<description></description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">6</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 30 Sep 2014 00:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
<content:encoded>In 2007 hadden we de geweldige klassieker Romeo en Julia op onze school. Vele uren oefenen, veel werk en veel plezier leverden een prachtige voorstelling op waar ouders, broers en zussen, neven en nichten en vrienden en vriendinnen hebben genoten van vakwerk op het podium.
Het plezier en de kwaliteit spatten van het podium. Een echte Rembrandt voorstelling onder de bezielende leiding van Mette Spruit. In het fotoboek krijg je een goede indruk van deze voorstelling. Er is ook een prachtig fotoboek verschenen.
 </content:encoded>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: could you paste the xml too?

Comment: XML is added now thanks!

Comment: the xml is not valid. Thats why its failing: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: The validator gives the error 6 The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
for line 2. But I don't entirely understand what it means.

Comment: youre using html entities

Comment: Yeah but I decode these entities before parsing the xml

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain it that well. Since my update it does load all the entries because I decode the HTML entities. But now UTF8 characters show up in my strings.